# What's the point of column ordering in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the Bootstrap 3 documentation they give the following example of Column Ordering: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

Why would you not just define this as:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-9">.col-md-9</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
</div>
```

or if it had to be the opposite way:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
   <div class="col-md-9">.col-md-9</div>
</div>
```

It's like defining something the "wrong way" and then overriding it to get it the "correct way" unless I've misunderstood this?

Comment: See this link http://www.schmalz.io/2014/10/08/Column-Ordering-in-Bootstrap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column ordering is used to create different responsive layouts. Take a [look at this demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/a0RsCr6qOp) and resize the viewport width. You can use ordering to switch the layout depending on screen width.

**Larger screens:**

[image]

**Smaller (mobile) screens:**

[image]

So we want the sidebar on the left on *large screen*s, but we want the main content to be first on *mobile screens*. This is one of the more common use cases, but there are many.

Since Bootstrap is "mobile first", the default grid tier is the smallest (xs) tier. When the markup doesn't specify an `xs` column size, the columns will stack vertically on mobile screens. The columns will stack in there natural order. For this reason, your markup should always be set for the layout of the smallest screen, then use the push/pull classes to adjust the layout for larger screen widths.

[More on column ordering](http://blog.codeply.com/2015/04/06/responsive-bootstrap-layouts/)